# How to bind/trace django cache variable

Tags: django, bind, trace, django-channels, django-cache

I would like to save some value in Django cache and bind a trace function to it, so as soon as the value changes I would like to call a function. After the trace function has been called I would like to remove the bind.

#### Django Cache Code.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("MyVariable", value, None)
cache.get("MyVariable")
```

#### Pseudo Code:

```
def callbackFunction():
    print cache.get("MyVariable")
    cache.unbind("MyVariable", callbackFunction)        

def runOnce():
    cache.bind("MyVariable", callbackFunction) # Bind Cache Variable

runOnce()
cache.set("MyVariable", 123, None)
cache.set("MyVariable", 999, None)
```

Expected printed result:

123

Comment: That's... not a thing you can do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for commenting it. Using a workaround to avoid needing that.